# problem occurred while extracting the vsix to the experimental extensions path for javascript file

Tags: javascript, vsix, visual-studio-templates

Hi I tried to create vsix extension using asp.net project template with javascript file on it this is my code on vstemplate for my javascript file

```
 <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Administrator.js">Administrator.js</ProjectItem>
 <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="AdministratorCreate.js">AdministratorCreate.js</ProjectItem>
```

But I got this message when tried to build my vsix

**Error Problem occurred while extracting the vsix to the experimental extensions path. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft{path}\Administrator.js'.**

I really confused with this error and I cannot find the answer. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: having the same problem, I think that the paths are too long... maybe

Answer (score 4):

Reduce the characters in the product name or author in your manifest. The most likely reason is the path length.

The default path that is generated is %AppData%\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio<Experimental Version><Author><Product Name><Product Version>...
So anything that is in your control to reduce the length to below 255 chars should solve this issue.